# How to replace all commas (,) in a String with a commas between double quotes (",")?

Tags: java, android, string

If I have a string like this

`String names = {"lucy, john, frank"}` but I want the string to look like: `{"lucy","john","frank"}`

So I want to replace all commas with commas in double quotes (`","`)

I have `String newNames = names.replaceAll(",", "","");`   But this doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: It appears that you are actually trying to replace Java code in runtime? Remember that even if you have a string `"{}"`, it is still a string, not an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape double quotes in string literals.

```
String names = "{\"lucy,john,frank\"}";
String newNames = names.replace(",", "\",\"");
```

Also, using `String.replace` is already enough for your purpose. `String.replaceAll` is for regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `"` like `\"`

do instead :

```
String newNames = names.replaceAll(",", "\",\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will do it for any string

```
  public static String fun(String str) {
    return str.replace(".", "\",\"");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you were using PHP i would suggest `explode()` and `implode()`  but in Java you can use `String.split()` and `String.join()`. So what you want to do is:

```
String names = {"lucy, john, frank"};
String splitted = names.split(", ");
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Second, the `String.join` method does not exist in Java.

Comment: first look at the question and my answer and then talk to me, second StringUtils.join

Comment: The problem is that `String.join()` doesn't exist, only `StringUtils.join()`.